# Armazenar dados de uma constante como props

Tags: javascript, html, react

Tenho a seguinte constante:

```
const: lista = [{
 id: 1,
 poke: 'Pikachu',
 desc: 'Pokemon do tipo elétrico',
}, {
 id: 2,
 poke: 'Squirtle',
 desc: 'Pokemon do tipo água',
}]
```

E preciso de um componente para que receba esses dados como props, porém não sei a sintaxe para receber esses dados como props em um outro componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você passa ele como uma propriedade do seu componente:

```
<SeuComponente lista={lista} />
```

Aí no componente "SeuComponente" você conseguirá chamar ele via props:

```
this.props.lista
```

E aí terá o valor que você passou anteriormente.

Espero ter ajudado.